# DynamoDB table design for storing computed data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am preparing single table design for DynamoDB. I have reviewed amazon's document and some other blogs too for understand concepts and best practices which needs to be followed during table design, but still some of questions are not clear where i need help.

Just to give you background, I have prepared entity diagram, access patterns etc, Planning to build a service which will compute data end of day i.e. daily, monthly and yearly. Data volume - 50,000 devices * 48 data points in a day.

**Main entities**

- Sites (Site ID, Site Name, Location)
- Devices (Device ID, Device Name, Device configuration parameters)
- Device Log(LogID, Datetime, consumed energy) - These data are coming based on 30 minutes interval.

**Access Patterns**

- Get total power consumption for a Site in a Year or within date range
- Get monthly power consumption for a site based on date range i.e. How much in Jan'23, Feb'23 etc.
- Get daily power consumption for all devices in a site or selected devices for a site

**Questions**

- Planning to use Site ID as PK i.e. Site#1
- Device ID as SK DeviceID#100, DeviceID#200 etc.
- Would like to store computed data of power consumption for year, month and a date so no need to perform any computation at the time of retrieval, can you suggest for this is okay to use SK like YEAR#2023, store yearly data, DEVICE#100#YEAR#2023, DEVICE#100#YEAR#2023#MONTH#01, DEVICE#100#YEAR#2023#MONTH#01#DAY#01
- Can you suggest in above example which attribute is advisable for GSI1PK and GSI1SK?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp should be your sort key as your main access patterns is to retrieve things with a time based pattern.

To ensure uniqueness you may also need to append the deviceID to the timestamp.

Your GSI can then be deviceId as PK and the siteId as SK.